# Creating a tip for responsive background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

At start, it's a very generic question, so all replies will be welcome.

So, I have some design, full page background, and some text, which will be html text. And this text is connected, using white line, and this white line points to red dot. I think, red dot will be positioned absolute, but then some questions arrive:

It's responsive view, so when resizing, background image will change width, so red dot should follow this pointed area (is this possible ?)

Also, I'm looking for a way to connect this red dot with html exmplanation box.

I have searched, but could't find anything, that suits my needs.

Also, I'm not expecting that anybody will write full code for me--but I need some clues, how to start this ...

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What kind of Google terms did you enter? I can image 'responsive tooltip plugin' could give quite a lot of results which could inspire you? In any case, it doesn't seem to be very difficult: with some jQuery code and perhaps a plugin you should be able to get this working without a huge effort.

Comment: I dint know, how to title this correctly, and your rwd tooltip pluign sounds great. Ill check, thanks.

Comment: @MarekBrzeziński Did you see this: http://www.inabrains.com/tooltip/examples/image-hotspot.html

Comment: Here's something I was playing with a while ago, it's close to what you need, I think http://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/yuo8s0xz/

Comment: Yes, nice, but i need something which works not using hower, but all times visible...

Comment: This one is closer, 'ill try to personalise this and i tell you, if this works, because in my opinion, its worth to know this technique.
http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Connect-HTML-Elements-with-Lines-HTML-SVG-Connect/

Answer (score 1):

You can design it for a large screen (for example 1440 wide pixels) and then scale with CSS depending on the percentage you need. You can make a js function to this purpose:

(Note that's only an example)

```js
function resizeMe() {
  var initialHeight = 1440;

  var displayHeight = $(window).height();
  var percentage = displayHeight / initialHeight;
  $(".your-element").css("transform", "scale("+percentage+")");
}
$(function() {
  $(window).bind('resize', function() {
    resizeMe();
  }).trigger('resize');
});
```

```css
.your-element {
  background: url(http://dummyimage.com/1440x768/000/fff&text=Big+Image) top left no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body,html { height: 100%;margin:0; }
.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 230px;
  right: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  border:1px solid black;
  color: black;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="your-element">
  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Il will use / test this for red dot item. And now, i will need to archive conencting line effect....

Comment: This method allows you to scale all the content inside. If you achieve the white line to connect the box with the dot all your content will be resized. I don't know how to achieve it without canvas.